# Sorting by alphabet List of Lists

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I had an exercise where I had to put duplicate elements from List to individual lists. Everything works fine, but my question is how to order it alphabetic now, so the result starts from `List(a,a,a,a,a,a)`, not from `List(e,e,e,e)`
Tried to use `sortBy` in the end, but none combination worked for me.

My code:

```
val list2 = List('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e')
def sortedSublist(l: List[Char]): List[List[Char]] = {
  l.groupBy(identity).map{case (key, values) => values}.toList
}

println(sortedSublist(list2))
```

Current result is:

```
List(List(e, e, e, e), List(a, a, a, a, a, a), List(b), List(c, c), List(d))
```

Comment: `.sortBy(_.head)`?

Comment: you are right, it works, but how? Could you build it up for me? Would be grateful. What is `head` in this case?

Comment: that's the head of each list

Comment: `.map{case (key, values) => values}` === `.values`

Comment: I'm wondering how it goes into each `List`. No matter if we have List("stringgg", "str", "string") and we do `.sortBy(string => string.length` or we have List of Lists, how does `sortBy` go "into" each list? If we had List(List(List('a','a,'a'))) would we also use only `.sortBy(_.head)`?

Comment: sort by applies the function to each element of the list and orders the list by the result of that function

Answer (score 0):

*mck* suggested a good answer.

You can also sort the map by key after groupBy

```scala
l.groupBy(identity).toList.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)
```